# AWS ECS container exiting without specific reason

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs

ECS service is exiting after running for a couple of seconds. In case we make a container out of the image manually it is running fine, command: sudo docker run -i -p 9100:9100 -p 9110:9110 -p 9120:9120 -p 9130:9130 847782638323.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/bytemark/cap

ECS logs are as follows:

```
2017-01-23T19:37:00Z [INFO] Created docker container for task bytemark-cap:2 arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:847782638323:task/5d0c49a2-9591-469e-b05b-ebbaaefac26e, Status: (CREATED->RUNNING) Containers: [bytemark-cap-container (CREATED->RUNNING),]: bytemark-cap-container(847782638323.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/bytemark/cap:latest) (CREATED->RUNNING) -> c8ee05c5cd688209939d96b54cb0c74c4122686036362d7bfa19f85bdc2dd56e
2017-01-23T19:37:00Z [INFO] Starting container module="TaskEngine" task="bytemark-cap:2 arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:847782638323:task/5d0c49a2-9591-469e-b05b-ebbaaefac26e, Status: (CREATED->RUNNING) Containers: [bytemark-cap-container (CREATED->RUNNING),]" container="bytemark-cap-container(847782638323.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/bytemark/cap:latest) (CREATED->RUNNING)"
2017-01-23T19:37:01Z [INFO] Task change event module="TaskEngine" event="{TaskArn:arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:847782638323:task/5d0c49a2-9591-469e-b05b-ebbaaefac26e Status:RUNNING Reason: SentStatus:NONE}"
2017-01-23T19:37:01Z [INFO] Adding event module="eventhandler" change="ContainerChange: arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:847782638323:task/5d0c49a2-9591-469e-b05b-ebbaaefac26e bytemark-cap-container -> RUNNING, Ports [{9100 9100 0.0.0.0 0} {9110 9110 0.0.0.0 0} {9120 9120 0.0.0.0 0} {9130 9130 0.0.0.0 0}], Known Sent: NONE"
2017-01-23T19:37:01Z [INFO] Adding event module="eventhandler" change="TaskChange: arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:847782638323:task/5d0c49a2-9591-469e-b05b-ebbaaefac26e -> RUNNING, Known Sent: NONE"
2017-01-23T19:37:01Z [INFO] Sending container change module="eventhandler" event="ContainerChange: arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:847782638323:task/5d0c49a2-9591-469e-b05b-ebbaaefac26e bytemark-cap-container -> RUNNING, Ports [{9100 9100 0.0.0.0 0} {9110 9110 0.0.0.0 0} {9120 9120 0.0.0.0 0} {9130 9130 0.0.0.0 0}], Known Sent: NONE" change="ContainerChange: arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:847782638323:task/5d0c49a2-9591-469e-b05b-ebbaaefac26e bytemark-cap-container -> RUNNING, Ports [{9100 9100 0.0.0.0 0} {9110 9110 0.0.0.0 0} {9120 9120 0.0.0.0 0} {9130 9130 0.0.0.0 0}], Known Sent: NONE"
2017-01-23T19:37:01Z [INFO] Redundant container state change for task bytemark-cap:2 arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:847782638323:task/5d0c49a2-9591-469e-b05b-ebbaaefac26e, Status: (RUNNING->RUNNING) Containers: [bytemark-cap-container (RUNNING->RUNNING),]: bytemark-cap-container(847782638323.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/bytemark/cap:latest) (RUNNING->RUNNING) to RUNNING, but already RUNNING
2017-01-23T19:37:01Z [INFO] Sending task change module="eventhandler" event="TaskChange: arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:847782638323:task/5d0c49a2-9591-469e-b05b-ebbaaefac26e -> RUNNING, Known Sent: NONE" change="TaskChange: arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:847782638323:task/5d0c49a2-9591-469e-b05b-ebbaaefac26e -> RUNNING, Known Sent: NONE"
2017-01-23T19:37:01Z [INFO] Task change event module="TaskEngine" event="{TaskArn:arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:847782638323:task/5d0c49a2-9591-469e-b05b-ebbaaefac26e Status:STOPPED Reason: SentStatus:RUNNING}"
2017-01-23T19:37:01Z [INFO] Error retrieving stats for container c8ee05c5cd688209939d96b54cb0c74c4122686036362d7bfa19f85bdc2dd56e: context canceled
2017-01-23T19:37:01Z [INFO] Adding event module="eventhandler" change="ContainerChange: arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:847782638323:task/5d0c49a2-9591-469e-b05b-ebbaaefac26e bytemark-cap-container -> STOPPED, Exit 0, , Known Sent: RUNNING"
2017-01-23T19:37:01Z [INFO] Adding event module="eventhandler" change="TaskChange: arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:847782638323:task/5d0c49a2-9591-469e-b05b-ebbaaefac26e -> STOPPED, Known Sent: RUNNING"
2017-01-23T19:37:01Z [INFO] Container c8ee05c5cd688209939d96b54cb0c74c4122686036362d7bfa19f85bdc2dd56e is terminal, stopping stats collection
```

Is there a way to debug the actual cause of the ECS service exiting.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the reason shown in ECS Console.

Answer (score 0):

If you can SSH into the docker instances (if you made it through ECS and specified a key or are using your own instances) you can get the logs from the docker.

I had an issue where my only docker container was dying after a few seconds so you can list the containers with

```
docker ps -a
```

Find the container you want to see the logs for and use

```
docker logs *container id*
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments. In case I check for docker logs for the specific container which have exited running, there is none. The logs which I have posted in my original post are logs for the amazon/amazon-ecs-agent:latest from the server which is responsible for creating other containers in the ECS instance.

Comment: The agent container automatically gets removed when it fails, you can try spamming the following to get something    "docker logs $(docker ps -a -q)"